# integrate matplotlib into android app?

Tags: android, python, matplotlib

I've been playing for some time with python and matplotlib and managed to create some neat desktop applications. [like graphical analysis tool for linear algebra, rendering engine for maps etc.

I was wondering if I could turn these applications into android apps. I'am completely new to android. I plan to use python (though I'm good with java) for the coding (I know this is possible with tools such as kivy or SL4P).

I want to know the limitations for using these tools in android. Can I even get matplotlib into android? I searched everywhere, but couldn't find how to go about a matplotlib based android app.

Any kind of pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can embed [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) on an Android device (or any other kind of smartphone or tablet).

One alternative possibility would be to make your app connect to a back-end server that has matplotlib, and use that to generate the figures and send back images to the client.

- Advantage: Can potentially get a working mobile prototype finished somewhat quickly by reusing existing code.
- Disadvantage: The app cannot work offline since it relies on your central server.

Comment: is there any particular reason why such tools have not been developed as of now? as in what is the bottle neck here that is preventing matplotlib from working on an android device?

Comment: @deepak I'm not an expert, but I believe matplotlib requires NumPy, which I believe would need to be ported. In addition, matplotlib uses different back-ends depending on the GUI, so an interactive version would need that too. However, it is conceivable you could use a headless back-end to create static images.

Comment: so what would it take to port NumPy?

Comment: Are lapack and blas ported to android?

Comment: Well, lapack and blas could be ported if you have a Fortran toolchain, which you can find on the Internet, e.g. http://specificimpulses.blogspot.com/2011/01/my-android-speaks-fortran-yours-can-too.html or build yourself. But that's not necessary if you can tolerate lower performance because Numpy (at least 1.7.1) can be built for android with it's own lapack/blass implementation in c.

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib cannot be compiled for android, numpy can though:

https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/issues/detail?id=260